# Angular google maps - ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs, rest, angular-google-maps

I'm trying to load multiple maps in a loop (ng-repeat) using Angular Google Maps (http://angular-ui.github.io/angular-google-maps/) but getting the following error:

```
angular-google-maps: could not find a valid center property
```

Below is the code, storeOwners is retrieved from a rest API and store.center is an object returned as follows:

```
center: "{"latitude":-33.87787,"longitude":18.49352}"
```

Apologies for this fomatting :(

```
<div class="media" ng-repeat="store in storeOwner.stores">
    <div class="media-left media-middle">
      <ui-gmap-google-map class="media-object" center='store.center' zoom='17'></ui-gmap-google-map>
    </div>
 </div>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The center property must be a valid JSON so, for example:

```
store.center = {
    "latitude" : -33.87787,
    "longitude" : 18.49352
}
```

I don't know if your `center: "{"latitude":-33.87787,"longitude":18.49352}"` is a typo (" at beginning and end)....

Comment: Got to the bottom of it, the server was returning json_encoded data so it was surrounded by ". Thanks